# ValueError: AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long

Tags: python, encryption

This code fragment worked, and then started failing with

> ValueError: AES key must be either 16, 24, or 32 bytes long

This is in Python 3.3.5.

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

salt = '!%F=-?Pst970'
key32 = [ ' ' if i >= len(self.salt) else self.salt[i] for i in range(32) ]
bkey32 = str(key32).encode('utf-8')

cipher = AES.new(bkey32, AES.MODE_ECB)
```

The AES constructor fails with the ValueError listed in the title.

bkey32 is:

```
b"['!', '%', 'F', '=', '-', '?', '\\x7f', 'P', 's', 't', '9', '7', '0', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']"
```

I count that as 32 bytes.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are  creating the `str` representation of your list, you need to `join` the contents of the list:

```
key32 = "".join([ ' ' if i >= len(salt) else salt[i] for i in range(32) ])
bkey32 = key32.encode('utf-8')
```

`str.join` creates a single joined string:

```
In [19]: "".join([ ' ' if i >= len(salt) else salt[i] for i in range(32) ])
Out[19]: '!%F=-?Pst970
```

Or use `str.format`:

```
salt = '!%F=-?Pst970'
key32 = "{: <32}".format(salt).encode("utf-8")
cipher = AES.new(key32, AES.MODE_ECB)
```

Answer (score 3):

By call `str` on the list object, the string become list representation; includes `[`, `]`, quotes around characters.

Just, use [`bytes.ljust`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.ljust) to get 32 bytes:

```
salt = b'!%F=-?Pst970'
bkey32 = salt.ljust(32)[:32]   # [:32] is unnecessary if you're sure `salt` is less than 32
# bkey32 => b'!%F=-?Pst970                    '
```